# Get text inside a div and place it as a value of another attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, return-value

I need to get the text inside each 'dd' and place it as a value of the data-description attribute of the related 'a.myClass'. It would be perfect if the data-description attribute is created only if 'gallery-caption' is present.

HTML

```
<dl>
    <dt>
       <a class="myClass"></a>
    </dt>
    <dd class="gallery-caption">This is my caption</dd>
</dl>
```

CURRENT JS (non-working)

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){

     var Caption = $(this).find('dd.gallery-caption').text();

     $(this).attr('data-description', Caption );

});
```

Thanks for your help

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION**

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){
     var Caption = $(this).parent().next('dd.gallery-caption').text();

     if (Caption && Caption !== ''){
         $(this).attr('data-description', Caption );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `dd.gallery-caption` is not a children of `.myClass`, so try this with `.next()`:

```
var Caption = $(this).parent().next('dd.gallery-caption').text();
```

Here you traverse up to its parent and then go at next level of dd and find the `.gallery-caption` class and take the text out of it.

Although same can be achieved with `.siblings()` too:

```
var Caption = $(this).parent().siblings('dd.gallery-caption').text();
```

Here you traverse up to its parent and then get the sibling at same level and find the `.gallery-caption` class and take the text out of it.

Comment: Thank you I could correctly reach the desired content with your first solution. I combined it with the if statement @Syon provided, I'll update my question with the final solution. Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
$(this).parents("dl").find('dd.gallery-caption').text();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check it before setting it? Also, data attributes can be accessed by using `.data("description")`.

Also, your selector for `Caption` needs tweaking.

Try this:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){

     var Caption = $(this).parents("dl").find('dd.gallery-caption').text();

     if ($(this).data("data-description")) {
         $(this).data('description', Caption);
     }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/taju4/

Answer (score 2):

You needed to go a little higher up the chain to find your caption:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){
     var Caption = $(this).closest('dl').find('dd.gallery-caption').text();
     if (Caption && Caption !== ''){
         $(this).attr('data-description', Caption );
     }
});
```

If you have multiple DD/DT's inside the DL then you'll need to use next():

```
var Caption = $(this).parent().next('dd.gallery-caption').text();
```